# Tracking first time users Mixpanel?

Tags: cookies, mixpanel

I got [this blog](https://blog.mixpanel.com/2015/01/06/community-tip-tracking-first-time-users/) link about distinguishing between first time and returning users. From what I understand I will set a super property ("First Time") for every user who comes on my website as "True"(treating all users brand new) if that super property isn't set else if it is set as "True" I will change it to "False". But the code given in the above blog doesn't seem to be doing that.

```
mixpanel.track("Home Page Viewed");
mixpanel.register({"First Time": "FALSE"});
```

Where is it checking if "First Time"property is already set or not? Or is there any fault in my understanding ?
Also super properties will expire once the cookie expires as they are stored there. So how to persist them ? Increase the cookie lifetime ?

Comment: How could you achieve it ?